# Listview Control No column headers

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing **C++ MFC** application. There I have *list view control*.

1. I define control variable (`m_listCtrl`) under `CListCtrl` class (
       resource view add variable )
2. I add columns as following code snippet

[image: Output]

No column headers and columns. Any help is appreciated.

```
static void AddData(CListCtrl &ctrl, int row, int col, const char *str)
{
    LVITEM lv;
    lv.iItem = row;
    lv.iSubItem = col;
    lv.pszText = (LPSTR)str;
    lv.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    if (col == 0)
        ctrl.InsertItem(&lv);
    else
        ctrl.SetItem(&lv);
}


BOOL CmfcTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    //.. default code in MFC for dialog here        
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, "Page");
    m_listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(0, 60);

    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, "Last Modified");
    m_listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(1, 80);

    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(2, "Prioirty");
    m_listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(2, 50);

    m_listCtrl.SendMessage(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

    AddData(m_listCtrl, 0, 0, "First");
    AddData(m_listCtrl, 0, 1, "Jan 2011");
    AddData(m_listCtrl, 0, 2, "Medium");

    AddData(m_listCtrl, 1, 0, "Second");
    AddData(m_listCtrl, 1, 1, "Feb 2011");
    AddData(m_listCtrl, 1, 2, "High");

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Comment: I assume the control has the LVS_REPORT style?

Comment: @Steve I did not add any type of style

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a dialog template you have to set the style for the headers there.

Click on the control in the resource editor. Make sure you have the style **Report** selected (section Appearance, property **View**).

In the section appearance, set **No Column Header** to **No**

If you create the list view by your own code, don't use the style **LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER**

The style for a column header is define negative. So you set the style if you want to suppress the header. Most other styles are defined positiv, you want them so you set the style. Sometime confusing.